# How to Navigate from React Native Component to Native iOS UIViewController

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-navigation, navigator-ios

I've integrated React Native into an existing native Objective-C iOS app. I need to navigate from a React Native Component to a native UIViewController, and back.

I'm currently trying to get a Native Module to work but, while my Native Module is called from the Javascript, pushViewController and presentViewController do nothing when called.

I have also looked into [NavigatorIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigatorios.html), but I don't see anything in the documentation that shows how to navigate from React Native to native. The same goes for [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/).

I've also looked into [React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/), but still don't see a way to navigate to native view controllers.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

No official documents said anything about navigating back from RN to native.
Native Module is the correct approach.

I think you could revisit your Native Module code and debug any potential issue there.